# Using Public/Private key pair as proof of delivery

Tags: security, rsa, digital-signature, private-key

## The problem

I'm working on a mobile application where `user A` should **physically** delivery something to `user B`, and the user `A` MUST prove that delivered it.

There is a restriction:

- User A or User B might be offline on the delivery, so it can not rely on internet connection

## My approach

I thought about using cryptography to solve this problem:

When the delivery is scheduled, the following process occurs:

1. A key-pair is generated, and stored on database.
2. The private key belongs to `User B` and should be transfere to his mobile app.
3. Some `well-known+delivery_uuid` string is encrypted using the public key, and transferred to the `User A`.
4. User A is oriented to only show the encrypted code (in form of a QRCode) if the delivery occurs.
5. User B is oriented to read the QRCode using the mobile app when delivering.
6. Since the encrypted message begins with a `well-known` string, the `User B` mobile app can decrypt it and verify that the message is OK. The application store the `delivery_uuid` part if valid, and sends to server-side to keep track as soon as user get internet access.
7. If the `User B` try to fake the `delivery_uuid`, it will obviously not match.
8. If the `User A` try to fake the QRCode, the `User B`'s app will not be able to validate the message.

## Concerns

1. The fact of a `well-known` piece be present on every encrypted message can make it weaker? Considering that the key-pair is used just once.
2. The public key should NOT be visible to anyone. Only the back-end must use it to create the delivery proof message. Same obviously apply to the `delivery_uuid`
3. Sh*t happens. If the user B mobile app somehow crashes and loose the `delivery_uuid` before sending it to back-end, the `user B` will need to rely on `user A` honesty.
4. How strong must my keys be? Considering the monetary value of the package is low. Is RSA the better encryptation in this case?

I really know that this question is complex, but I really appreciate if someone can help-me with it.

*Note:* I'm not sure that Stackoverflow is the right stackexchange community to ask about this, please comment if it's offtopic. But since it have something about logic, I think that's the right place.

Comment: Too complex and misconceptions: To demonstrate authenticy use digital signature, not encryption.  Do not transfer private keys. Public keys are visible by definition. You need a proof belonging to user B, not to user A, so the message/qr should be signed/generated by B. Note: Probably the correct comunity to this message is security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your description misses one important fact: Is it a requirement that the process works offline or can an existing online connection of A and B be assumed when A meets B for handing out the delivery?

Comment: "User A or User B **might be offline** on the delivery, so it **can not rely on internet** connection"

Answer (score 3):

Seems a little complicated. Why not

1. UserB (and every user who installs the app to receive deliveries) is issued a public/private key pair. The private key is held only by UserB; if it is lost, a new pair can be issued. Meanwhile, the public key is public, and is stored in a database along with UserB's identity.
2. Upon receipt of the delivery, UserB generates a simple text document containing the date and time, the QRCode, the name of the person receiving the package, or whatever information is needed. The document also contains the public key. Any format will do.
3. UserB signs the document with his private key and appends the signature to the end of the document. Now you have a cleartext document spelling out everything that happened, and proof that UserB agreed to it.
4. UserB shares the document with UserA, and/or uploads it anywhere that is needed, e.g. system of record. Both UserA and UserB can keep an offline copy.
5. If proof of delivery is ever needed, UserA just needs to produce the signed document.

Comment: Basically "sign a receipt". The equivalent of using paper

Comment: Sorry for the late comment: I've read your idea a few days ago, but didn't understood. I'll read it with care. Since I'm trying to find a "perfect" solution, I'll keep the question open for other answers, and also put a bounty on it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The question is: I need to ensure that the QRCode is authentic, not a faked one by UserB. This code will be used for UserA to receive his payment. I just need to know if: The QRCode is authentic and it belongs to that transaction specifically.

Comment: Isn’t it enough that the client agreed the code is valid, since he signed the receipt?

Comment: Lets call UserA the Seller and UserB the Buyer: The seller must proof that he he met and delivered the product to the buyer in order to receive the payment. The buyer show a QRCode that only he and the server knows. But the seller don't know the code, and is offline, so he can't ask the server about the code authenticity. We must provide a way to seller verify that the QRCode is authentic and related exactly to that transaction.

Comment: Sorry @Elias but I don't understand the malicious use case. Hacker fakes a QRCode, then what? He tricks the seller into taking his money?

Comment: If the malicious user fake the QRCode, the seller will deliver the product and never receive his money (actually he will need to contest the payment...). The question is ensure that the QRCode isn't faked or related to another sale.

Comment: @Elias I'm sorry, what you are describing makes no sense. Payment is driven by delivery, right? And the malicious user can't fake proof of delivery without the buyer's private key. Faking an *order* is an entirely separate problem (and possibly not solvable, depending on the details). Am I missing something? Maybe you could add a step-by-step threat profile to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem correctly, there are three parties here :

- The verifying party, which is your back-end.
- The selling party, which is User A.
- The buying party, which is User B.

Also I do not buy the idea that "The public key should NOT be visible to anyone". They are meant to be, that's why they are called public.

Now, In order to make sure that the item was delivered

- By User A
- To User B,

We can have the following setup.

1. The verifying party ( i.e. the backend ) generates a token, associates it with the buyer, the seller, item and persists the info.
2. The verifying party encrypts the token with User A's ( seller ) public key.
3. The verifying party encrypts the already encrypted token with User B's ( buyer ) public key.
4. The verifying party sends the double encrypted token along to User B. Since it has been encrypted with User B's public key, only User B can read it.
5. User B decrypts the double encrypted token using his private key and saves the result in his device. The result is now encrypted with User A's public key, which means only User A can read it.
6. When User A comes to deliver the item, User B hands over the encrypted token as acknowledgement. This can be done via a QR code scan.
7. User A decrypts the encrypted token with his private key and keeps it in the device.
8. Whenever it is feasible ( in terms of availability of internet ) to prove it to the back-end, User A encrypts the token with the backend's public key and sends it along to the back-end.
9. The back-end decrypts the encrypted token with its private key and does a lookup in its persistence store, matches the buyer and the seller and completes the verification.

Answer (score 1):

Use signatures and not encryption.

0) The app, as distributed, contains the public portion of a keypair only the server knows.

1) Every user that installs the app **generates** a keypair, keeping the private key, and uploading the public key to a database.

2) When a delivery is scheduled, the server generates a delivery ID and creates a message containing:

- The Delivery ID
- The deliverer's (user A's) public key fingerprint.
- The recipient's (user B's) public key fingerprint.

A will receive this message and signature prior to making delivery. B can, but need not receive it prior to delivery.

3) When A meets B, A can off-line transfer the message and signature to B. QR code would be difficult, depending on key size, but NFC would certainly work. B can verify the server signature and know that the message has not been falsified or tampered with. A can transfer his public key to B and B can verify its fingerprint via the signed message. A can prove he is who he says he is by creating a signature with the private key belonging to the public key that was just transferred and verified.

4) B can prove who he is by creating a signature with the public key matching the fingerprint in the delivery message. B would have to transfer his public key to A if A didn't already have it, and A can verify it matches the fingerprint stored in the message.

5) B can certify receipt by creating a signature on a message saying so (however you want to format that) and off-line delivering it to A. A can then present this to the server, which the server can verify because it has B's public key.

Comment: Marking you question to earn the bounty as it's closer to my own answer. But not marking it as right yet since I want to make the question open to another answers! Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick : btw, if you are using signature, you are in effect using encryption.

Comment: @Gautam Yes and no. You're using cryptography for sure, but encryption changes the original data to be unreadable and a signature attaches additional data.

Comment: @CJ, My comment was more related to the fact that signature = hash + encryption . But Never mind . :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that:
- A has a key pair.
- B holds a delivery UUID.
The goal is to enable B to provide a proof that only A can provide.

As previous answers this can be solved by digital signature. You should let B and A to enchange the necessary information. B should provide the delivery Id, and A must sign it.

- You need to hold the public keys of the partners.
- You need to provide a way for the information exchange, bluetooth perhaps?

I believe that you may need more than this simple protocol.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answers, I've formulated a solution to the problem. I'm posting it as answer to know from everyone comments about it validity.

First, let give names to the actors to simplify:

- User A is the Seller
- User B is the Buyer

## The use case

1. The *buyer* decides to buy, and make the payment. Now he talk with the *seller* to combine the delivery.
2. After payment confirmed, the *back-end* generates an `UUID` , and associate it with that `transaction_id`. Let's call it `delivery_uuid`. By the business logic, only the *buyer* have access to it.
3. The *buyer* app requests the `delivery_uuid` to the *back-end*, which produce a message containing both the `delivery_uuid` and the `transaction_id`, then digitally sign this message. Lets call this `delivery secret`
4. The *buyer* app will keep this message in storage.
5. When both *seller* and *buyer* meet, and the buyer checks if the product is OK, then he gives the `delivery secret`, using a QRCode or NFC.
6. With the `delivery secret` in hands, the seller's app can check the `delivery secret` authenticity (using the application's public key), then store it to send to *back-end* as **proof of delivery** as soon as he have internet access.
7. Now that the *back-end* have the **proof of delivery**, the payment to the seller is made.

### Considerations

#### Buyer signature to the message

I think that it's not necessary, since by the *back-end* conception, only the *buyer* have access to the `delivery secret`. If the `delivery secret` leaked, certainly I'm in a bigger trouble.

#### Seller signature to the message

Also not necessary, the only concern about the seller is that he needs to send the `delivery secret` to the back-end. If he loose the cellphone, that's not our problem. If the application crashes and the `delivery secret` is lost, then we have a problem.

#### Server signature

This signature allow the seller to make sure that the `delivery secret`

- Belongs to the right transaction, preventing the the buyer to use an authentic `delivery token` from another transaction.
- Have a valid `delivery_uuid`
- Make sure that `delivery secret` is still valid (we may add a validity to it)